# Is it possible to have a Pi as an access point that forwards packets to another Pi that's connected to the internet?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, internet

Essentially a long range wifi extender. What I'm wondering is possible if whether you can have a setup such that a user can connect to the first Pi, make an HTTP request that gets forwarded to a second Pi that's also an access point (which is connected to the internet), and the second Pi retrieves the data and routes it back to the user through the first Pi.

This is through using several Raspberry Pi 3Bs.

Comment: Sounds like a job for OpenVPN, I currently have a Pi I connect to which forwards traffic, it shouldn't be too difficult to set it up to forward traffic to another Pi to actually process requests. I'm afraid I can't provide any detailed guidelines on that though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)